# Kotlin - removes spaces around buttons

Tags: kotlin, button, alignment

I'm playing around with the code. Below is my code, and it seems like there's some default spacing causing the buttons to be separated. I would like to remove the spaces, so button "A" sits right on top of button "B". Could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

```
fun MyUserInterface(){
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .padding(32.dp)
    .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Red))){
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "A")
        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "B")
        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "C")
        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "D")
        }
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "E")
        }
}
```

}

Comment: What platform is this for?  JavaFX/Swing/AWT?  Android?  iOS?  Qt?  SWT?  LibGDX?  Grails?  Some other desktop, web, or mobile framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify spacing for the whole column use `Arrangement.spacedBy`:

```
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy((-8).dp),
```

Comment: it's working. I tried spacedBy(0.dp) before, but never tried the negative value :-). Thanks for your help.